# Mean of abs(Gauss) as a function of the standard deviation?

Tags: normal-distribution

I want to produce Gaussian noise with mean 0 and the absolute value on average 100. Emperically I see that random guassians (0, 125.31) gives me 100. What is the expression I must use so that I can plug in any value $x$ in place of 100 to get the corresponding $\sigma$ instead of 125.31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of the absolute value of a normal variable with mean zero is equal to the mean of a half-normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution

So the answer is

$\sigma = x \sqrt{\pi/2}$

which you get from the mean formula of the wikipedia page with $\mu=0$.

Comment: Yes, when you take the absolute value is like you fold it!